# Can't show caption image modal with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a problem on show caption on image modal.

```
    .controller('HomeController',['dataProvider','$scope','$location', '$modal', '$log', 'authService',
    function(dataProvider, $scope, $location,$modal, $log, authService){
        $scope.imageurl = [
            {
                'url': '/uploads/home/tenda kerucut.jpg',
                'thumbUrl': '/uploads/home/tenda kerucut.jpg',
                'caption': 'Tenda Kerucut',
                'size': 'Ukuran 3x3 m, 5x5 m'
            },
            {
                'url': '/uploads/home/tenda konvensional.jpg',
                'thumbUrl': '/uploads/home/tenda konvensional.jpg',
                'caption': 'Tenda Konvensional',
                'size': ''
            }
        ];

        $scope.open = function (item) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/partials/layouts/modal-home.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    imageurl: function(){
                        return item;
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
            $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
        };
}])

.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, imageurl) {
    $scope.item = imageurl;
});
```

This my view

```
<div class="ui-product-thumbs grid-33" ng-repeat="image in imageurl">
            <a ng-click="open(image.url)">
                <img ng-src="{{image.thumbUrl}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="ui-product-info">
                <p>{{image.caption}}</p>
                <div class="text-center">{{image.size}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this my modal

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <img class="img-full-width" ng-src="{{item}}">
    <p>{{image.size}}</p>
</div>
```

After i run my codes, it can't show caption image on my modal. Please help me, how to show a caption on my modal when I click?

Comment: `ng-click="open(image)"` and use `{{item.url}}`, `{{item.caption}}`, `{{item.size}}`, etc in your modal template

Comment: I've been add {{item.caption}} on modal template, it still null (can't show a caption).

Comment: If your code has changed and it still doesn't work, update the code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simplify this a lot.

First, change your `<a>` tag to `ng-click="open(image)"` so you're passing the entire object and not just the URL.

Then, in your `HomeController`...

```
$scope.open = function(image) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/partials/layouts/modal-home.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.image = image;
        }
    });
};
```

Then your model template can reference `{{image.url}}`, `{{image.caption}}` and any other image object property, eg

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <img class="img-full-width" ng-src="{{::image.url}}">
    <p>{{::image.caption}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @SkripsiRico this is basically the same as my comment above so I'm not sure why that didn't work. Anyway, you're welcome

Comment: What is the :: inside {{ }}?